# How can I detect the device running my application with React Native?

Tags: react-native, device-detection

I would like to use different styles depending on the device running an iOS application.

How could I detect which device is running the application?

Answer (score 1):

Device detection is enabled by [`react-native-device` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device) available from npm

`npm install react-native-device --save`

See also: https://github.com/GertjanReynaert/react-native-device

Comment: Flow raises `Duplicate module provider` error with `react-native@0.4`. I've opened an issue on GitHub at https://github.com/GertjanReynaert/react-native-device/issues/1

Comment: How do you detect react running in a page?